# how to assign function to marionette.template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

As per I know, `marionette.template` accept either `jquery selector` or `compiled template string`.

If I write code like in the following way, working fine

```
 exports.ProductInfoView=Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        domInfo:{
            mainTemplateId:"tagProductListTpl",
            tableTemplateId:"taginfoViewTpl"
        },
        template:commomFunctions.templateCompilation("tagProductListTpl",""),
        onRender:function(){
            this.templatingProductInformation();
        },
        modelEvents:{
            "change:currentJson":"templatingProductInformation"
        },
        templatingProductInformation:function(){
            console.log(this.el);
            //this.el.innerHTML=commomFunctions.templateCompilation(this.ui.mainTemplateId,"");
        }
    });
```

Note :`commonFunctions.templateCompilation()` accept `templateId` as first argument and `data` as second argument. It will compile `handlebars template` and it return compiled template.

If I assign that return value to `template`, working fine.

I want to make data for templating,so I am passing `function` to `template like in the following way.`

```
exports.ProductInfoView=Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        domInfo:{
            mainTemplateId:"tagProductListTpl",
            tableTemplateId:"taginfoViewTpl"
        },
        template:function(){
            return commomFunctions.templateCompilation("tagProductListTpl","");
        },
        onRender:function(){
            this.templatingProductInformation();
        },
        modelEvents:{
            "change:currentJson":"templatingProductInformation"
        },
        templatingProductInformation:function(){
            console.log(this.el);
            //this.el.innerHTML=commomFunctions.templateCompilation(this.ui.mainTemplateId,"");
        }
    });
```

This way also working fine, If you observer I hard coded `templateId("tagProductListTpl")` inside function.But I don't want like that. I want to use like `this.domInfo.mainTemplateId` instead of hard coding. that way it's not working fine.

It's throwing error. I know it's out of scope. but how can I achive this.

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I will advise you to rewrite `Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.compileTemplate` which is responsible for template compilation. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913709/how-to-integrate-handlebars-template-to-marionette-view/25915155#25915155) post, there almost the same issue.

```
Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.compileTemplate = function (yourRawTemplate) {
        // In case if template is function
        if (_.isFunction(yourRawTemplate)) {
            return yourRawTemplate;
        } else {
            return Handlebars.compile(yourRawTemplate);
        }
 };
```

And if you loading template files from remote server you also need to rewrite `Backbone.Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.loadTemplate`. Here example:

```
Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.loadTemplate = function ( templateId ) {
    var template = '',
        templateUrl = 'path_to_your_template/' + templateId + '.html';

    // Loading template synchronously.
    Backbone.$.ajax( {
        async   : false,
        url     : templateUrl,
        success : function ( templateHtml ) {
            template = templateHtml;
        }
    } );

    return template;
};
```